# String values to boolean check

Tags: java

I have four string falgs  get these values as string a[].

```
falg1 = Y or N

falg2=  Y or N

falg3=  Y or N 

falg4=  Y or N
```

Based on above falgs ,i am checking the below cases.Is it correct way of doing it or do you have any better appraoch?

```
if (falg1.equals("Y")) {

    if (falg2.equals("Y")) {

        if (falg3.equals("Y") && falg4.equals("Y")) {
            condition = true;

        } else

            condition = flase;
    } else
        return null;
} else
    return null;
```

Comment: That's not your real code - it's invalid Java. It's pointless us checking invalid code.

Comment: did you mean to write `==`?

Comment: I think you mean "flag", not "falg".

Comment: ***HOW ARE YOUR "falg" VARIABLES DECLARED??***

Comment: Updated my question.Sorry for missing that.Just i given psuedo code.

Comment: even pseudocode should be readable, and not riddled with typos.

Answer (score 1):

`=` is assignment not equality. You can't check for String equality using `==` since it is an object, you will have to use `string1.equals(string2)`.

You can have `char` flags instead if you want to keep using 'Y' or 'N' then you can use `==` to check for equality between `char`s.

However, it would be easier to just use a `boolean` flag1, flag2, flag3, and flag4. That way you can just do this:

```
boolean flag1, flag2, flag3, flag4;

// set all flags to whatever values

if (flag1 && flag2)
{
    if (flag3 && flag4)
       condition = true;
    else
       condition = false;
}
else
{
    return null;
}
```

Comment: this can be shortened to `condition = flag1 && flag2 && flag3 && flag4`.

Comment: not really @Femaref, should be: `return (flag1 && flag2) ? (flag3 && flag4) : null;`

Answer (score 0):

```
 if (!falg1.equals("Y") || !falg2.equals("Y"))
     return null;

 return falg3.equals("Y") && falg4.equals("Y");
```

This is assuming none of the values can be null. You can deal with that by doing `"Y".equals(falg1)`

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to use `equals()` to compare String values in Java.
2. To optimize boolean expressions, use a table. Put all the possible values in it and the expected results:

   ```
   flag1 flag2 flag3 flag4  |  result
   ----------------------------------
     N     N     N     N    | null
     Y     N     N     N    | null
     N     Y     N     N    | null
     Y     Y     N     N    | null
     N     N     Y     N    | null
   ...
   ```

   Y     Y     Y     Y    | true

   When you do this, you will often see a pattern emerge which will help you optimize the code. See [Truth Tables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truth_table).
3. There are a lot of typos in your code; you really should fix them.

Answer (score 0):

Well...

I'm assuming a couple of things.

- falg = flag.
- flags can be Boolean.

Here is my approach.

```
Boolean flag[4];

//initialize flags somehow. 

if(flag[1] && flag[2]){
    if(flag[3] && flag[4])
        condition = true;
    else
        condition = false;
}else{ 
     return null;
}
```